# MariaDB/MySQL joining tables on a range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, mariadb

I have a table which includes an IP address:

```
create table login_history
(
    id         int auto_increment primary key,
    ip         int unsigned,
    created    datetime(6)  not null,
    user_id    int unsigned not null,
);
```

and another table with an IP range:

```
create table ip2location
(
    ip_from      int unsigned not null primary key,
    ip_to        int unsigned null,
    country_code char(2)      null,
)
```

I am trying to join both tables with the following "on" expression.

```
select * from login_history
left join ip2location_db1  on
    ip2location_db1.ip_from <= login_history.ip_int and ip2location_db1.ip_to >= login_history.ip_int
```

It's working fine, but it's very slow. How can I improve the performance of such a query?
I already added indices on the IP columns of both tables.

Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!

Comment: A performant solution to IP searching:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

Comment: Awesome tipp. Thx!

Comment: Btw, there is a small typo here http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipv4.sql in line 266, there the table is named 'IpS' instead of 'Ips'

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed.  (I probably last tested it on Windows where table names were case-insensitive.)

Comment: That was a very enlightening read. You can enjoy an XXL Banana Latte today. Enjoy it as I enjoy your knowledge.

Comment: Got it; thanks.  That should keep me well caffeinated for an XXLong time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is:

```
select lh.*,
       (case when ip.ip_from <= lh.ip_int then ip.country)
from (select lh.*,
             (select ip.ip_from
              from ip2location_db1 ip
              where ip_to >= lh.ip_int
              order by ip_to
              limit 1
             ) as ip_to
      from login_history lh
     ) lh left join
     ip2location_db1 ip
     on ip.ip_to = lh.ip_to;
```

This can then take advantage of indexes on `ip2location_db1(ip_to)`.

Comment: Thx for that great answer. Is that possible to use in an UPDATE statement? Let's say the login_history has a country column, I want to fill with the information from the ip2country table without losing this performance boost?

Comment: @ZenCoding . . . Yes.  But this question is about a `SELECT`.  You should ask another question about `UPDATE`.  By the way, how much better is the performance?

Comment: It cost about a quarter of the time now. I will ask another question. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I created a new question. I also added a little bit more of the real complexity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034973/mariadb-mysql-update-statement-with-multiple-joins-including-a-ranged-join